# Codes, How fun?! ^_^

Tags: cipher

Each code is a word, find all 3 words.

The codes to crack:

CODE 1 :

[image][image][image][image]

CODE 2 :  .. ...

CODE 3 :

```
X^   *!   ^*
```

```
XX   ^X   X*
```

```
!X   X*   X^
```

```
^X   XX   !X
```

```
X*   !X   ^*
```

```
X*   XX   X!
```

HAVE FUN, GOOD LUCK!

Comment: I will add hints if needed

Comment: What are we looking for?

Comment: Each code is a word, Find out all 3 words.

Comment: First one looks like FATE? :)

Comment: @GintasK It seems to me like the first line of Code 3 didn't have asterisks next to the "!" and "^" originally.

Comment: @pime , yes but when I pressed edit, I saw taht the input was this way, just it formatted it wrong, I think it should be a  6x6 grid with X!*^ symbols in it, right OP ?

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense considering the rest of the code. Thanks

Comment: Each line of code 3 should be a 3 by 2. 1st 2 on the top 2nd in the middle and 3rd last.

Comment: @SoRelatable I submitted an edit formatting the Code 3 as 3x2 blocks like you said, but looking at the answer, I'm not sure it made sense. Please reject if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Code 1:

> Masonic Cipher for "This" (solved by @pime)

Code 2:

> Morse Code for "is" (solved by @pime)

Code 3:

> Each letter is represented by 3 sets of 2 symbols, like:
>
> `X^   *!   ^*
> XX   ^X   X*
> !X   X*   X^
> ^X   XX   !X
> X*   !X   ^*
> X*   XX   X!`
>
>
>  If we stack these sets on top of one another, we get:
>
> `X^  XX  !X  ^X  X*  X*
> *!  ^X  X*  XX  !X  XX
> ^*  X*  X^  !X  ^*  X!`
>
> Now X represents a dot in [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille), so we get the word "Answer"

So the whole text is

> This is Answer

Comment: Don't know how to place `code` into spoiler :/ Can somebody edit?

Answer (score 12):

Partial, not yet worked out third code:

> Code One: Masonic Cipher, "This"
>
> Code Two: Morse Code, "is"
>
> Code Three: ?

Comment: Your close, you got the first 2 right

Comment: could be Sparta? :D

Comment: Could be, but I think correct answer is the one with an explanation, which I have yet to work out :)

Comment: It's not Sparta, If you want I can give you a hint

Comment: Not yet :) As I understood each line links to a letter, and is formed of symbols X*^!

Comment: Yes each line of the third code is a letter. But what code is it?

Comment: Do not work the 3rd code out; the puzzle is over. Instead, use the one posted as accepted.